# backgroundDisabledColor error when upgrading from Flex3 to FlashBuilder 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flexbuilder, mxml, flash-builder

I've upgraded a FlexBuilder3 project to FlashBuilder4, and I am seeing many compilation errors regarding unsupported tag attributes:

> The style 'backgroundDisabledColor' is only supported by type 'mx.controls.TextInput' with the theme(s) 'halo'

Here is the offending mxml element:

```
<mx:TextInput  x="245" y="86" id="code1" maxChars="15" change="enableButton(event)"  cornerRadius="9"  borderStyle="solid" backgroundDisabledColor="#7977b6" />
```

...what is the best workaround for this particular error? I was able to easily resolve a similar error with the "backgroundColor" attribute by changing it to "contentBackgroundColor", and was hoping there was a simple workaround for backgroundDisabledColor as well. I realize I can apply a css style, but I'd rather have a simpler solution as there are many many other attribute errors similar to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect if you add this as a compiler argument it should work:

-theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc

Once you specify the Halo theme, I would expect that the errors will just go away.

More info from this blog:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/14/using-the-halo-theme-in-flex-4/

Alternatively, you could revert your app to Flex 3 using the Flash Builder "multiple SDK" feature.

Comment: Thanks Jeffry. You do a great podcast, btw.